# How can I add built-in rules to make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Make(1) has built-in rules, such that for simple tasks you don't need a makefile at all. I can type `make prog` and if the current directory has a `prog.c`, make will do something useful.

I have a number of rules like this (e.g., how to make `.pdf` from `.html`) that apply in many projects. If I have a makefile in a directory, I can simply include my rules from a file. Is there a way to tell make to use this file always? Like a dot file that make would always include before doing anything else.

Comment: GNU make probably doesn't do this, but other make-programs (such as the BSD's pmake) are setup to use a system-wide configuration file in which you could modify the predefined rules.

Comment: The obvious answer to "how do I make built-in rules" is "you modify the source of `make` itself, and rebuild it with your new built-in rules".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make's rules are truly built-in, not read from a file.  This has advantages (the entirety of make is one executable and you can copy it and install it anywhere and get identical behavior) and disadvantages (you can't modify the default rules without modifying the source code and recompiling--if you want to do that it's easy to do, though: see the `default.c` file in the sources).

You can specify an extra makefile (or makefiles) that should be parsed before the usual ones using an environment variable, though, so you can create a makefile with some extra rules, then (in your `~/.bashrc` or whatever) set [the `MAKEFILES` environment variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKEFILES-Variable.html) to the name of that file (or files) containing these extra rules (don't forget to export it).

Now every make invocation will load these rules as well.

You may discover, though, that this isn't quite what you'd hoped, because it could cause other makefiles to fail or act in bizarre ways (for example if you download open source packages and want to build them locally, etc.)  If you do this just remember you did it, so in a few months if you run into issues you'll remember to try undoing it and see if it helps :-)

Comment: This sounds right. Maybe I can make a `mymake` alias that sets `MAKEFIELS` and invokes `make`. This way I can still avoid putting Makefiles in directories that don't need them, but also avoid messing up other people's Makefiles.